# How to save hex value from string in uint8_t or char without converting the value?

Tags: c++, string, hex, uint8t

I have a binary file which I am reading and saving as hex values. These hex values will be used to flash a device, but I need the hex values to be stored as either uint8_t or char (preferably uint8_t). Currently the values are stored in a string, and only one byte at a time. What I want to do is to store the value as uint8_t instead of string.

So if the value of `std:string result` is `0x3A`, I want the value of `uint8_t flash[1]` to be `0x3A`, and not `58` or some other value.

How can this be achieved?

Any help is appreciated :)

EDIT:

As I first expected, and has been confirmed, the values are the same whichever method I am using.
For those who wish to see the code generating the string, here it is:

```
unsigned char x;
std::ifstream input(file, std::ios::binary);
input >> std::noskipws;

std::stringstream stream, str;
stream << std::hex << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << (int)x;
std::string result( stream.str() );

str << result;
int value;
str >> std::hex >> value;
uint8_t data = value;
```

Comment: You know that `0x3A` IS `58`?

Comment: You can't read or save as hex values - hex is a representation. Everything is stored as bits, which can be represented binary, decimal, hexadecimal, and what have you.

Comment: Yes, I am fully aware of that. But I need the value to be stored in that fashion, and NOT as 58.

Comment: It is stored as 00111010. Both are stored as 00111010, unless you've invented a computer with 16-way switches or something.

Comment: If you read a byte into memory, it's always stored in *binary* format. How you which to *present* that binary value (decimal, hexadecimal, octal, binary) is irrelevant, the data is still stored as binary ones and zeroes.

Comment: You should probably look into the [`std::hex`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/hex) stream modifier.

Comment: Thank you for all answers :)
I am already using std::hex to convert from string to uint8_t, but the values I wrote to the flash doesn't seem to be the same values I write from the flash right after. Therefore I thought it might have been something in the way I write the values.

Comment: But since it is the same (which I initially thought), that can't be the problem

Comment: Maybe post the code you are using so we know exactly what you are doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to fully understand what you are saying we really need to see the code that puts data into your `std:string result`.

However this may be of help:

```
std::string result;

result += 58; // this is the same as

result += 0x3A; // this
```

The compiler assumes the *first* append is a decimal number because it does not begin with a `0` and converts it from decimal to binary before appending it to the string.

The compiler assumes the *second* append is a hexadecimal number because it begins with  `0x` and converts it from hexadecimal to binary before appending it to the string.

In both cases the *same* binary number is appended to the string.

Now to put that into your array we can do:

```
uint8_t flash[2]; // big enough to our 2 chars

flash[0] = result[0]; // copy first value
flash[1] = result[1]; // copy second value
```

Voila!, all done.

Answer (score 0):

`0x3A` IS `58`. They're represented the same in binary and mean exactly the same thing - the only difference is the formatting when output to the user (integers, by default, are output in base 10).

If you're trying to represent 58 as `0x3A` in the output stream, just change the way you're outputting it.

Answer (score 0):

A value is a value, `0x3A == 58`. There is no difference, is if you put it in an `uint8_t` is is exactly the same. There is nothing like storing it as 58 or storing it as 0x3A. It both ends up as: `00111010`.

You can use the `strtol` function to convert a hexstring to `uint8_t` and use 16 as your base number.